# Scala code run successfully in Eclipse but its jar not run

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, sbt

Scala code run successfully in Eclipse but its jar not run

I have Scala project with SBT, its run well in Eclipse but when I try to run jar file which is generated after packaging is not running its throw error like

SBT version= 0.13.8 ,scala version =2.12.2 ,java=1.8

[Click here to seethe Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acqcO.png)
[click to see the build.sbt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8JL5.png)

Please co-operate me to solve this issue

Comment: Please edit those details in to the question, with appropriate formatting - click the "edit" link just under the main part of the question.

Comment: Maybe you have to add the required classes from the Scala-runtime to your classpath?

Comment: Have you set the correct version of Scala in your `PATH`. It seems likely you're using two different versions of the Scala SDK within eclipse and your local machine, hence the class is not found, as it was added/removed in a later version. If you have a terminal in eclipse try: `which scala`, `which sbt` to see which versions are used by eclipse, then try the same on your machines command line. They may be the same, they may be different. If they're different you have found the problem

Comment: How did you build the jar?

Comment: When you build a jar using `sbt package` this jar will only contain your code. And since your code depends on the **Scala*" STD library, you need it in the class path for running. A simple solution for local development is running the jar using **Scala** instead of **Java**: `scala - jar path/to/jar`. For distributing _(deploying)_ your application the simplest solution is using the [**sbt-assembly** plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) to build a jar which contains all your other dependencies, so you can run this jar in any place that has **Java**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez you should have written it as an answer.

Comment: @michaJlS,build the .jar file  using sbt command like sbt clean , sbt compile and sbt package

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez , i have try "scala  -jar abc.jar"  then its show bad option: '-jar'

Comment: @KishorJumde My bad, it is just `scala test.jar`

Answer (score 0):

This Error due to then dependency is not included in the jar file at the time building the project  , so its throws ClassNotFoundException , we can fix this issue by assemlying the dependency into single jar . for this solution please follow the below link

https://alvinalexander.com/scala/sbt-how-build-single-executable-jar-file-assembly/